# grub error unknown filesystem - Really need help!

Tags: grub2

I have a windows 8 Pc and I installed ubuntu onto it in dual boot, I made a recovery disk and deleted the Ubuntu partition but now I get "grub error unknown filesystem" when booting from the disk and booting normally, Please can someone help me I'm only 13 and if my parents find out they won't be very happy - I have a windows 8 laptop (My Dads) and a Windows 7 Pc (My Mums) I can use to do something with? Please I really need help on how to get Grub working again so I can get my Pc booting again.

- Thanks

Comment: Was Windows 8 pre-installed or an install you did. If pre-installed you should just be able to go into UEFI menu and choose to boot Windows. You may have to turn UEFI on or even turn on secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you deleted Ubuntu, you deleted all the files grub needs to run also.  To fix, you need to either reinstall grub, with its files sitting in a /boot/grub directory you create on one of the FAT partitions Windows likes to have around for tools/recovery, or restore the Windows boot block.  The grub approach I've done successfully, make the directories, and from a live media, mount the fat partition you selected, for example sda1:

```
sudo mount -tvfat /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
```

Then run

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/sd1/boot /dev/sda
```

You should have a working grub again.
*** Untested, dangerous below ***
  The other approach of restoring the Windows boot block requires you to have a real set of install media, not the typical crippleware the vendors foist off.  If you can get to the "Recovery Console", you should be able to run fixmbr and/or fix boot and things should work again.  Vendor supplied media have no way to get to a recovery console, but lock-step you through their script straight to a reinstall (with no guarantee of fixing the mbr).  Another possible fix which I have no experience with is to find a backup boot block on the Windows root directory and from the live media, use dd to write it to the beginning of the disk.  Worst case is another non-function boot loader, so go back to installing grub.

Good luck